# How do I display username in a custom block?

Tags: blocks, sessions

Am new to Drupal so this is a very fundemental question.

How do I display the current username ? In a custom Block? I beleive is the `$user->name` session variable.

**Do I create a Custom Block Type?**  If so how do I reference the username?

**Do I edit files on the file system?**  If so which files?

**Do I create new files?** If so where?

In other web frameworks the templating engine allows server script tags... ex.. like

`<%= username %>`

Ive tried putting

`$user->name`  and `{{app.user}}`

into the custom block editor but nope, I've learned it's a WYSISYG with no way to render

All I want to do is display a user name in a block I can add a label too.

Any help appriciated.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90093/discussion-on-question-by-kickaha-how-do-i-display-username-in-a-custom-block).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this in sevaral ways, one of this could be use a `preprocess function`. In your custom module in the `.module` file or your custom theme in the `.theme` file (recommended) write this:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_HOOK().
 */
function [my_module_or_theme]_preprocess_block(&$variables) {
  $variables['username'] = \Drupal::currentUser()->getUsername();
}
```

and then in your template suggestions of `block.twig.html` print the variable `{{ username }}`

Comment: This pointer looks very helpful, thankyou. It points out how to do the username lookup programmatically which as a beginner is an important step to really understanding Drupal. I'll come back to accept once I'm up successfully and running with a custom module / theme.

Comment: Not exactly the answer I needed, but close enough to have helped.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

To answer my question I created a custom module with a block.

That needed a folder for the module, a .info.yml file and a file for the block.

1) A folder for the module `modules/custom/my_show_user`

2) The file `modules/custom/my_show_user/my_show_user.info.yml`

```
name: Show User Module
description: Displays the logged in user name in a block.
package: Custom

type: module
core: 8.x

dependencies:
  - drupal:block

php: 5.6
```

3) The file `modules/custom/my_show_user/src/Plugin/Block/UserNameBlock.php`

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\my_show_user\Plugin\Block;

use Drupal\Core\Block\BlockBase;

/**
 * Provides a 'User Name' Block.
 *
 * @Block(
 *   id = "my_show_user",
 *   admin_label = @Translation("Show User"),
 *   category = @Translation("Show User"),
 * )
 */

class UserNameBlock extends BlockBase {

    /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function build() {
    return array(
      '#markup' => $this->t(\Drupal::currentUser()->getUsername()),
    );
  }

}
```

That's it done. .

fyi, any time a change is made clear the cache to see it
`Manage>Configuration>Performance>Clear All Caches`

In Structure > Place Block a block called `UserNameBlock` can now be selected and it displays the current logged in user.

Adding the dependency `- drupal:block`  and keeping the commented annotations @Block and @inheritdoc was key.

the line

`'#markup' => $this->t('any html string can go here ' . 
                        \Drupal::currentUser()->getUsername() . 
                        ' concatenated with data in the template, in this case username' ),`

is the entry point for your 'custom template'.

Answer (score 0):

public function build() {
return [
'#markup' => $this->t(\Drupal::currentUser()->getUsername()),
];
}